# im trying to display the full name like the output did , but whenever i hit enter the program just print out 1 word rather than 2 word

Tags: c++, c

question
3. Reads full name and year of birth, then show the full name and age
Input: anonymous anonymous  2000
Output: Hello anonymous anonymous, this year you are 19 years old

can somebody help me how to display a full name in my code, and im very new about this programming thing

(the input and output has to be the same as the question)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char name[25]; 
    int birth; 
    int age; 
    scanf("%s %d",&name,&birth); 
    age = 2019 - birth; 
    printf("Hello %s, this year you are %d years old",name,age); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: In c++ you may find `std::getline` useful.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i've tried this

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
{
 char name[25];
 int birth; 
 int age;
 scanf("%s %d",&name,&birth);
 age = 2019 - birth;
 printf("Hello %s, this year you are %d years old",name,age);
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: I'm sure your prof gave you some slides with basic information. Use variables to store the data, a function that reads input from the user and a function that can print stuff on the console. All of this is very basic, and until you have read the slides, watched the lectures or looked at some beginners introduction to C we can't help. Try it yourself first, and come back with specific questions.

Comment: As you can see, code in comments look like a jumble. I've moved it to your question and formatted it, but you should check it over to make sure I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf`. Also give some `scanf` documentation a read-through. You might be surprised at how the `%s` format argument works.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` splits up the input string by whitespace characters. Therefore, the first `anonymous` will be put into the first %s token, but the second one won't. Without overcomplicating things and keeping `scanf` (which is mostly frowned upon due to buffer overflow issues etc), the quickest thing to do would be to have two buffers, one for first name, one for last name.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char firstName[25]; 
    char lastName[25];
    int birth; 
    int age; 
    scanf("%s %s %d",&firstName,&lastName,&birth); 
    age = 2019 - birth; 
    printf("Hello %s %s, this year you are %d years old",firstName,lastName,age); 
    return 0; 
}
```